# Black screen appears when use process attribute in monodroid activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, xamarin.android

From one activity my app will go to a second activity (I send some of this activities code here). This activity has a mapview. because that I have 2 mapview in my app I should to use 'Process' attribute in this activity.but when I use this attribute before lunching the activity app displays a black screen for some seconds and then my ProgressDialog and activity will display. I wanna that this black screen not appear

This is the definition of my class:

```
    [Activity (Label = "PropertyShowActivity",
           Process =":PropertyShowMapActivity")]            
public class PropertyShowActivity : MapActivity
{.....}
```

The onCreate code of this activity is:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        try {
            base.OnCreate  (bundle);

            RequestWindowFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            PD = new ProgressDialog (this);
            PD.SetMessage ("Please Wait...");
            PD.Indeterminate = true;
            PD.SetCancelable (false);
            PD.Show ();
            currentproperty = new Property ();
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.PropertyShow);
            mapLayout = FindViewById ,,,,<LinearLayout > (Resource .Id.PrptyLocationOnMapLayout);
            mapLayout .Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;



            if (RplSettings.Sitename == string.Empty) {
                RplSettings.LoadAllSettings (this);
            }
            action = Intent.GetStringExtra (AppConstants.Action);
            Pid = Intent.GetLongExtra ("Pid", 0);

            Common .MenuInitialize (this, "Property");
            Common .MenuEventInitialize (this);
            AssignBottomActionBarEvents ();

            FindElemnts ();

            if (Pid == 0)
                Pid = Intent.GetIntExtra ("Pid", 0);

            if (action == string.Empty) {
                PD.Hide ();
                Finish ();
            }
            if (action == AppConstants.DownloadProperty) {
                LoadPropertyData ();
            } else if (action == AppConstants.OfflineProperty) {
                OfflineProperty = true;
                //var path = Intent.GetStringExtra (AppConstants.PropertyFilePath);
                //currentproperty = IOAddOn.ParsePropertyJsonString (UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString (Property.LoadPropertyFromSD (path)));
                LoadPropertyData ();
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Common.HandleException (ex);
        }
    }
```

and also the logs of ddms is:
when I define my class such as below it works fine:

```
[Activity (Label = "PropertyShowActivity")]         
public class PropertyShowActivity : MapActivity
{.....}
```

Comment: Please help.this is so important for me.:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it bur running two app in same process.But after going to second activity i saved the state of new app in application class of app. and then when I back tp first map activity in OnResume i change the state of mapview to the past state.
It work right.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `Process` attribute you are telling the Android OS to start that activity in a new Process. Loading a new process can take time which is why the black screen appears (think of it as launching a new application). Unfortunately there is not much you can do to avoid this, other than optimizing your code (see below).

It appears you are doing a lot of work in your `OnCreate()` override like loading settings etc. You may want to run these in the background like this.

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
            {
                // load settings here
                // do expensive non-ui work here

                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        // do UI work here
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.Really the heavy process in loading iin the function loadpropertydata that is run a threadpull to do this process.and then back tp UiThread.

Comment: ifound that real problem is in this part:11-17 15:21:50.023: D/dalvikvm(8407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2985 objects / 199264 bytes in 74ms 11-17 15:21:50.464: D/dalvikvm(8407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 568 objects / 31736 bytes in 51ms 11-17 15:21:50.954: D/dalvikvm(8407): ..... GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3199 objects / 284848 bytes in 54ms 11-17 15:21:53.654: D/dalvikvm(8407): GREF has increased to 201 ------- when they end activity run.there is any solution to resolve it?

Comment: Those logs just indicate the DalvikVM is running garbage collection and the GREF (global reference) count has increased to 201. The issue is that it needs to start a new process. Unfortunately there is no way around this